# Returning XML Data in Tabular format when it isn't stored as XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have this XML data stored in a varchar(8000) column in a SQL Table, unfortunately not as an XML column.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfRate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Rate>
        <SituationID>1</SituationID>
        <SituationDescription>S</SituationDescription>
        <PaymentFortnight>8.40</PaymentFortnight>
        <PaymentRentLessThan>4.00</PaymentRentLessThan>
        <PaymentRentMoreThan>5.20</PaymentRentMoreThan>
    </Rate>
    <Rate>
        <SituationID>2</SituationID>
        <SituationDescription>M</SituationDescription>
        <PaymentFortnight>9.40</PaymentFortnight>
        <PaymentRentLessThan>5.00</PaymentRentLessThan>
        <PaymentRentMoreThan>6.20</PaymentRentMoreThan>
    </Rate>
</ArrayOfRate>
```

Despite it being a varchar column, is there a way I can get the data out into tabular format? There are many  but I've just shown 2 as a sample.

Such as the following:

| SituationID | SituationDescription | PaymentFortnight | PaymentRentLessThan | PaymentRentMoreThan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S | 8.40 | 4.00 | 5.20 |
| 2 | M | 9.40 | 5.00 | 6.20 |

I tried the following with just one of the columns as a start:

```
select
    a.b.value('Rate[1]/SituationID[1]','varchar(10)') as [ID]
FROM TableName.Rate.nodes('ArrayOfRate') a(b)
```

but get the following errors:

> Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 40
> The column prefix 'TableName' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

> Msg 9506, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
> The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml.

Comment: @DaleK - sure, have added to the post.Thanks.

Comment: Did you try casting it to XML and then do the usual stuff with nodes and values?

Comment: @DaleK - thanks, have expanded upon the question with what I tried

Comment: @siggemannen - thanks, have expanded upon the question with what i tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast it to `xml` before you can use XML functions on it.

But because it uses a UTF-16 encoding preamble, you would need to cast it first to `nvarchar`. This in turn implies it should have been kept as `nvarchar` at the very least anyway, and best to store it as `xml`.

You are also shredding at the wrong level, you need to descend to `Rate` in the `nodes` function.

```sql
SELECT
  SituationID = x1.Rate.value('(SituationID/text())[1]', 'int')
FROM Tablename tn
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CAST(CAST(tn.Rate AS nvarchar(max)) AS xml) AS xmlCol
) v
CROSS APPLY v.xmlCol.nodes('ArrayOfRate/Rate') x1(Rate);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/7UpLRX-T)